# SQL won't work? It doesn't come up with errors either

Tags: php, sql, function

I have PHP function which checks to see if variables are set and then adds them onto my SQL query. However I am don't seem to be getting any results back?

```
 $where_array = array();
   if (array_key_exists("location", $_GET)) {
       $location = addslashes($_GET['location']);
       $where_array[] = "`mainID` = '".$location."'";
   }
   if (array_key_exists("gender", $_GET)) {
       $gender = addslashes($_GET["gender"]);
       $where_array[] = "`gender` = '".$gender."'";
   }
   if (array_key_exists("hair", $_GET)) {
       $hair = addslashes($_GET["hair"]);
       $where_array[] = "`hair` = '".$hair."'";
   }
   if (array_key_exists("area", $_GET)) {
       $area = addslashes($_GET["area"]);
       $where_array[] = "`locationID` = '".$area."'";
   }

   $where_expr = '';
   if ($where_array) {
       $where_expr = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where_array);
   }

   $sql = "SELECT `postID` FROM `posts` ". $where_expr;

   $dbi = new db();
   $result = $dbi->query($sql);
   $r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

I'm trying to call the data after in a list like so:

```
      $dbi = new db();
 $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

 // get the info from the db 
 $sql .=  " ORDER BY `time` DESC  LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
 $result = $dbi->query($sql);
 // while there are rows to be fetched...   

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
          // echo data

        echo $row['text'];


       } // end while
```

Anyone got any ideas why I am not retrieving any data?

Comment: You could make this easier by posting what `$sql` contains before you execute it.

Comment: It's there already the $sql statement is on there and I add on after pagination offset calcs the SORT BY which is also on there

Comment: He means post the literal contents of `$sql` as it exists right before you do `$dbi->query($sql)`

Comment: What we'd like to see is the actual SQL sent to the database, not the code you used to generate it.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `mainID` = '1' ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: it works in phpymadmin and my db class it working fine!?

Comment: Forget it I fixed it!! just posting correction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
      // echo data

    echo $row->text;


   } // end while
```

I forgot it wasn't coming from an array!